# Firestore can not write date as collection name

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm trying to write to Firestore all the prices from different stocks. Structure should look something like this (although this might not be the best fitted for it, still thinking of it as in SQL) :

```
const d1 = new Date();
const result = d1.getTime();
console.log('Epochtime',result);
database.collection("stock1").doc("exchange1").collection(date).doc('prices').set({"price":"price_value"})
```

Now the problem is that I can't create a collection with a name that's a variable that contains date. I tried all the different types of it and I presumed that epoch time should work, as this is a number like: `1636213439908`. I always get the error: `Value for argument "collectionPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.` Although the exact same variable can be written as a value in a collection. So not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Just cast the epoch time to a string, it will work. Note that you'll need to cast it back to a long when you read it

Comment: So simple... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Document IDs in Firestore must be strings, so you'll have to convert the data to a string. While `date.toString()` will work, I highly recommend using a [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for the dates, such as `date.toISOString()`. These formats are designed to be both humanly readable and machine sortable.